# Windows Phone 7 indoor maps control

Tags: windows-phone-7, dictionary

I am developing an application for Windows Phone 7 which needs to display indoor maps. This is my first app for WP7. It should be fast and beautiful (with sliding animations, etc).

I see following ways to implement it:

- Movable canvas with polygons on it, but the sliding is quite slow as I will have about 500 polygons
- Implement backbuffer bitmap, but memory could be a problem.
- Implement own custom tiledlayer, but it's not so fast to implement.
- Use built-in map control and customize it somehow, but I am not sure if it's possible

And a common problem with all these solutions, but last one is that I have to implement sliding and zooming myself.

Are there any controls for such stuff? And if not and built-in map customization is not an option, what's the best way to implement sliding like in Bing maps. I've done it on winmob 6 by writing some formulas, but I guess there should be a better way in WP7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you set your images up, you could take a look at the [DeepZoomContainer on CodePlex](http://deepzoomcontainer.codeplex.com/). It has a WP7 control. You could also build your own version using the [MultiScaleImage class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.multiscaleimage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). A good tip when it comes to manually animating in Silverlight is to user the object's transforms rather than directly setting their Canvas position properties (e.g. Canvas.SetLeft()). The reason for this is is because the transforms are done on the GPU, making them much faster. If relevant, you can also use storyboards for fixed animations as these are also run on the GPU.